# Issues with django-channels deployment on elastic-beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, django-channels, daphne

I am working on deploying my django app on Elastic Beanstalk using gunicorn for my wsgi and daphne to handle asgi. I managed to get my app deployed but the websockets are not functioning properly.

I was able to test that the EC2 instance connects to the redis cache by running the code below on my elastic beanstalk environment :

```
eb ssh

source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate
cd /var/app/current/
python manage.py shell

>>> import channels.layers
>>> from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
>>> channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
>>> async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'foo': 'bar'})
>>> async_to_sync(channel_layer.receive)('test_channel')
>>> {'foo': 'bar'} # <---------- I was able to receive a response
```

However, I was not able to run the initiate the daphne server on my EC2 instance manually :
`daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 5000 tattoovalley.asgi:application`
The code above generated the following error : `ImproperlyConfigured( django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

However I have configured the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment module in my .ebextensions config file :
.ebextensions/01_env.config

```
option_settings:  
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
        /static: static
        value: static/

    aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:     
        WSGIPath: tattoovalley/wsgi.py
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: tattoovalley.settings
        PYTHONPATH: /opt/python/current/app/tattoovalley:$PYTHONPATH

    aws:elbv2:listener:80:
        DefaultProcess: http
        ListenerEnabled: 'true'
        Protocol: HTTP
        Rules: ws
    aws:elbv2:listenerrule:ws:
        PathPatterns: /ws/*
        Process: websocket
        Priority: 1
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:http:
        Port: '80'
        Protocol: HTTP
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:websocket:
        Port: '5000'
        Protocol: HTTP
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjHJc.png)

I have also checked if the port 5000 is active and I did not find any activity.

What could be the problem ? Is there a solution that I can use to fix the websocket connection

**UPDATED**

Here is my asgi.py file :

```
import os
import django
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from chat.routing import websocket_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tattoovalley.settings")
django.setup()
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

import chat.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your **asgi.py** file, I guess that you can make some changes:

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tattoovalley.settings")

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

# Now you can safely import other Django-related modules
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator

from chat.routing import websocket_urlpatterns

import chat.routing    <---- NOT SURE IF YOU STILL NEED THIS

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
    }
)
```

I hope these changes make everything work. It basically comes down to the fact that you are trying to import 3th party Django packages/libraries, which aren't instantiated yet in your settings file. That needs to happen first before you can import them.

Next to that, the `import django` && `django.setup()` are obsolete as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me !!